# How to maintain these html table input with proper alignment & margin consistent

Tags: html

i inserted some inputs with labels in html table.But their alignments  & margin arr Not consistent.image given below:
[image]

I saw some manual solution like using padding & margins for each inputs.But is there any easy way to do that.
 here is the source code: 
 **Updates: Almost Solved But Month tag still not in same size comparing to others.**

[image]

**Last Updates: Solved**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
       select{
           width:173px;
       }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <table style="">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Salary Entry</th>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>

       Month:  </td><td> <select name="SALMT" id="month" onchange="" size="1">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Month</option>
                <option value="01">January</option>
                <option value="02">February</option>
                <option value="03">March</option>
                <option value="04">April</option>
                <option value="05">May</option>
                <option value="06">June</option>
                <option value="07">July</option>
                <option value="08">August</option>
                <option value="09">September</option>
                <option value="10">October</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>  

    </td>
    <td>

          Year:</td><td> <input type="text" name="SALYR" value="">
    </td>       

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
         Employee ID:</td><td> <input type="text" name="EMPID" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
         Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="name" value="">  
    </td>       

  </tr>

 <tr>
    <td>
         Department Code:</td><td> <input type="text" name="DPTID" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
         Designation: </td><td><input type="text" name="designation" value=""> 
    </td>       

  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

please let me know for any information.thanks.

Comment: What do you want to achieve (precisely)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:
what you have to do is add two `td` in row;

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
select{
width:173px;
}
</style>

<table style="">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Salary Entry</th>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>

       Month:  </td><td> <select name="SALMT" id="month" onchange="" size="1">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Month</option>
                <option value="01">January</option>
                <option value="02">February</option>
                <option value="03">March</option>
                <option value="04">April</option>
                <option value="05">May</option>
                <option value="06">June</option>
                <option value="07">July</option>
                <option value="08">August</option>
                <option value="09">September</option>
                <option value="10">October</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>  

    </td>
    <td>

          Year:</td><td> <input type="text" name="SALYR" value="">
    </td>       

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
         Employee ID:</td><td> <input type="text" name="EMPID" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
         Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="name" value="">  
    </td>       

  </tr>

 <tr>
    <td>
         Department Code:</td><td> <input type="text" name="DPTID" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
         Designation: </td><td><input type="text" name="designation" value=""> 
    </td>       

  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any idea onhow can i make the month field equal sizewith others.please check the i just updated

Comment: updated now please check if it is ok then accept the answer

Comment: Nice @Soorapadman.But this time Month field increase few px extra than  other fields. got it you manually did select width:167px; .ok

Answer (score 1):

you can try this now a right solution

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
    <td width="20%">Month</td>
    <td width="40%"> <select name="SALMT" id="month" onchange="" size="1">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Month</option>
            <option value="01">January</option>
            <option value="02">February</option>
            <option value="03">March</option>
            <option value="04">April</option>
            <option value="05">May</option>
            <option value="06">June</option>
            <option value="07">July</option>
            <option value="08">August</option>
            <option value="09">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
        </select></td>
    <td width="10%">Year</td>
    <td width="30%"><input type="text" name="SALYR" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Employee ID:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="EMPID" value=""></td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" value=""> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Department Code:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="DPTID" value=""></td>
    <td>Designation:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="designation" value=""> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```